# creating dynamic forms using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, dynamic, model

Hello everyone I need to create some dynamic forms so users can configure feeds to their specification.

I have used ng-repeat to do the following:

1. For each feed a user needs to configure a new tab is created
2. for each property a feed has a label and input textbox is created.
   Markup:

   ```
   <tabset>
   <tab ng-repeat="feed in feeds" heading="{{feed.heading}}">
       <form role="form">
           <div class="row" ng-repeat="property in feed.properties">
               <div class="col-xs-6">
                   <div class="input-group">
                       <span class="input-group-addon">
                           <span>{{property.name}}</span>
                       </span>
                       <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{property.value}}">
                   </div>       
               </div>
           </div>
       </form> 
   </tab></tabset>
   ```

This works just fine with the backing json that I have however I am wondering what the accepted way of capturing the data for this kind of use case, obviously I won't know how many feeds or properties each feed has so I suppose I need to bind this to an array in some way.

The question is how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `ng-model`

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="property.value">
```

This way the textbox is bound to `property.value`. angular automatically updates `property.value` when you change the text in the textbox. You can use it in your JS just like any other variable. That's the beauty of angular.

Comment: sadly these inputs are dynamically generated, i imagine in this case it would mean any change to any input box would override the value of property.value. I need a model instance dynamically generated for each input that is dynamically generated by the ng-repeat.

Comment: No, it wouldn't. Every element created by ng-repeat has its own scope and will update only the corresponding value. E.g. feed2.property3.value. `ng-repeat` works pretty much like you would expect a "for each" in any language to work. Add a `<span>{{property.value}}</span>` to see it in action

Comment: so when i want to grab all of these models to send to the server how might I go about that, I didn't know this was possible!

Comment: They are updated in your feeds object. So you can just send the entire feeds back to the server, e.g. as JSON. Obviously depends on how the server expects the data. Add `<pre>{{feeds | json}}</pre>` to the bottom of your page, so you'll see what happens with your object

Comment: thankyou very much! I cannot believe I missed this functionality!