# Use ng-repeat to construct a form using 2 different json's

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to construct a variable form, I have the questions stored on one database table and the kind of question (text field, radio button) and the possible answers related to every questions on other database table. I need to show the questions (first json), I got this already working, and then show the posible answers, this is what I'm facing now (this is the second json, it has the id from the question which is related, and the kind and answer value) but I don't know how to put it inside the ng-repeat or what is the correct way to do this. I know this is a poor information but I'm very lost with this issue. I already checked other similar questions:

- [Using ng-repeat to pull data from 2 different JSON files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36540044/using-ng-repeat-to-pull-data-from-2-different-json-files)
- [creating dynamic forms using ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32778769/creating-dynamic-forms-using-ng-repeat)

On my controller I have the code to get the two json and show it on the view, but I don't know how to relate it.

Any help is welcome. Thank you.

Edit:

The questions json:

```
{
    "question": {
        "id": "1",
        "kind": "check-box",
        "statement": "This is a sample question, you can choose 3 of 4 posibilities"
    }
}
```

The answers json:

```
{
    "answers": {
        "id_questions": "1",
        "options": {
            "answers": [{
                "value": "New"
            }, {
                "value": "Open"
            }, {
                "value": "Close"
            }, {
                "value": "Erase"
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you put a sample json? Then it will be easier for us to understand the problem.

Comment: My assumption would be to have an intermediate step that zipps two lists together [question: [answers]]. Thus, rendering would be quite straightforward.

Comment: Yes @IvanDemchenko I asked this to the responsible of developing the web service and he says (don't know why) that it's not possible :(

Comment: Well, when how do you know which answer belongs to which question?

Comment: @IvanDemchenko I know it by the id, each question got an id, and also the answers have the question id which are belonging

Comment: @proktovief thus, you can construct a new structure (let's call it QAS), something like "[question: [answers]]". Representing such is a trivial task: you'll need nested ng-repeat. The thing becomes easier to grasp if you think about your template as a function: QAS -> HTML. Therefore, you need to prep your data to be displayed. I would say, this is is rather a common case and the function is a good candidate for a service.